# Recursively call method variable python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to produce a list that is recursively populated taking input from a method variable. (I believe)

My code:

```
class Register:
    cur_unit = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1, .25, .10, .05, .01]
    reg_amount = []

    def load_reg(self):
        self.reg_amount = float(input('Enter amount of money in register...\n'))

    def transaction(self):
        trans_amount = float(input('Enter the cost of the transaction...\n'))
        if trans_amount > self.reg_amount:
            print("I'm sorry, but we don't have enough money in the register to allow this transaction...\n")
        else:
            cash_paid = float(input('Enter how much money you will pay with...\n'))
            change_due = cash_paid - trans_amount
            new_reg_amount = self.reg_amount - change_due
            if new_reg_amount < 0:
                print("I'm sorry, but we don't have enough money in the register to allow this transaction...\n")
            else:
                new_reg_amount = round(new_reg_amount, 2)
                change_due = round(change_due, 2)
                print('\n' + str(new_reg_amount))
                print(change_due)
                for i in self.cur_unit:
                    if change_due - i >= 0:
                        return [i] + [cash_paid - i]


reg = Register()
reg.load_reg()
res = reg.transaction()
print(res)
```

Result which produces an undesirable result:

```
Enter amount of money in register...
200
Enter the cost of the transaction...
24.24
Enter how much money you will pay with...
50

174.24
25.76
[20, 30.0] # undesired result

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Desired result which would run through cur_unit and bring back each unit if the unit can be subtracted from cash_paid without change_due being equal to or less than 0: (this is for more details needed)

```
[20, 5, .25, .25, .25, .01]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I don't see any useful application for recursion here; the problem appears to be that you need to work through a tutorial on loops: `while` and `for`.

Comment: That's just supposed to be guidance; that tone is not intended.  You need a loop, not recursion.

Comment: is `for i in self.cur_unit:
                    if change_due - i >= 0:
                        return [i] + [cash_paid - i]` not a loop?

Comment: It only finds the first item you can afford, then returns that individual result.  You have a lot of code posted for the restricted problem you described; what is the overall goal, that you needed to supply all of this?

Comment: Usually the very first comment is "can you post more code" so in order to not to get comments like that I generally overpost the code, which so far seems to work. However, i have also put in the code as a comment where the undesired result is and I have also provided how I want the result to look. Is this too much information or not enough information?

Comment: Code can be either, or both.  See [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I still use this principle after all my years of coding.

Comment: BTW, I meant the overall goal of the *program*, not of the posting size.  Do you need the maximum quantity of items you can buy?  Closest total to your available funds?  All combinations?  Each of these is a long-solved problem on this site -- generally under the search term "target sum", which nobody knows until they've already solved it once or twice.

Comment: I'm trying to kinda learn that principle but being that this is my only resource for criticism on my code and that I know very little about programming in general, I'm very sure I'm not perfect at it. Can you just help me, please?

Comment: I just simply want to produce the currency units it would take to produce change_due. Think in real life if you are owed $5.36. How would that look like in real life? I want to do this with as little code that can be reproduced easily. I have gone through multiple iterations of this from simply an iterative style to a functional style and now my attempt at creating an object-oriented style.

Comment: I also put in the very first line (I believe) which should imply to you that I am unsure if what I am asking is actually what I am asking, but I did post the desired result so you can better understand what I am actually asking. I don't have a CS degree or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Prune pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051720/recursively-call-method-variable-python#comment108008422_61051720), this problem is better solved by iteration than with recursion. I wrote methods to do it either way in case you were curious: `split_change_r` is a recursive function and `split_change` is a cleaner iterative solution. Note that they assume your `cur_unit` list is already sorted.

```
class Register:
    cur_unit = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1, .25, .10, .05, .01]
    reg_amount = []

    def load_reg(self):
        self.reg_amount = float(input('Enter amount of money in register...\n'))

    def split_change_r(self, amount, l = []):
        next_cur = [a for a in self.cur_unit if a <= amount][0]
        if next_cur == amount:
            return l + [next_cur]
        else:
            # here is the recursive call
            return self.split_change_r(round(amount - next_cur, 2), l + [next_cur])

    def split_change(self, amount):
        r = []
        while(amount != 0):
            next_cur = [a for a in self.cur_unit if a <= amount][0]
            amount = round(amount - next_cur, 2)
            r.append(next_cur)
        return r


    def transaction(self):
        trans_amount = float(input('Enter the cost of the transaction...\n'))
        if trans_amount > self.reg_amount:
            print("I'm sorry, but we don't have enough money in the register to allow this transaction...\n")
        else:
            cash_paid = float(input('Enter how much money you will pay with...\n'))
            change_due = cash_paid - trans_amount
            new_reg_amount = self.reg_amount - change_due
            if new_reg_amount < 0:
                print("I'm sorry, but we don't have enough money in the register to allow this transaction...\n")
            else:
                new_reg_amount = round(new_reg_amount, 2)
                change_due = round(change_due, 2)
                print('\n' + str(new_reg_amount))
                print(change_due)
                return self.split_change(change_due)

reg = Register()
reg.load_reg()
res = reg.transaction()
print(res)
```

Example output:

```
Enter amount of money in register...
200
Enter the cost of the transaction...
24.24
Enter how much money you will pay with...
50

174.24
25.76
[20, 5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.01]
```

Comment: By the way, this problem could get more interesting if you try to keep track of the actual bills and coins in the register.

Comment: ^^This is eventually what I want to do. I will be looking at this answer in a bit but I do need to step away.

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to hard-code any method input, ie: `transaction(200, 24.24)` but I didn't really realize I could use a variable from a method as the input. I ultimately wanted to not have to create another method and it under the `transaction()` method.

Comment: Actually you should prefer to split up your code into lots of functions that have [only one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), uh, function, each. One benefit of this is that it's easy to change your code if you only have it written out once and reference it elsewhere (rather than changing the code in every place). It also makes your code easier to read by grouping low-level operations into a single higher-level call with an informative name. You will find it easier to use lots of functions now that you know you can pass parameters to them like in my example.